# Textbox Formatting In SSRS 2008 - Break Line

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, ssrs-2008

So, say I have the following string

```
THIS IS STUFF (MORE STUFF)
```

How would I get the string to format as such in a textbox in SSRS?

```
THIS IS STUFF
(MORE STUFF)
```

This data is pulled from a single field in a query and I will not be able to manually inject a break line.

Also, sometimes the (More Stuff) is not in the field.

Extra examples:

STUFF AND THINGS

THINGS (STUFF)

THINGS AND STUFF (MORE STUFF)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to insert a line break into the string, i.e. set the textbox expression as something like:

```
="THIS IS STUFF" & vbcrlf & "(MORE STUFF)"
```

So the expression in a single textbox:

[image]

Will render as:

[image]

You can see there is a line break even though the string could fit on one line.

**Edit after comment**

OK, we need to handle various existing strings at the report level.

To do this, I would suggest using Custom Code, i.e. a function like:

```
Function SplitString (fieldValue As String) As String
  If IsDBNull(fieldValue) OrElse IsNothing(fieldValue) Then
    SplitString = ""
  Else If InStr(fieldValue, "(") > 0
    SplitString = RTrim(Left(fieldValue, InStr(fieldValue, "(") - 1)) & _
      vbcrlf & Right(fieldValue, Len(fieldValue) - InStr(fieldValue, "(") + 1)
  Else
    SplitString = fieldValue
  End If
End Function
```

I'm suggesting this as SSRS expression are notoriously brittle, and the lack of short circuiting means that what works for one string might display `#Error` on another. You could get around this with numerous `IIf` statements but Custom Code is much neater and easier to understand.

You can call the function with an expression like:

```
=Code.SplitString(Fields!MYFIELD.Value)
```

Either in a textbox expression or as a Calculated Field in the Dataset. The above works for me on your data:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I should have clarified that the text is within a single string pulled from a query. Although, legitimate answer, sorry about that!

Comment: Will the string be in a predictable form to be split? On your base string, you could split the string based on the `(` character for example, and insert the vbcrlf in the middle based on this. Or you could do it based on length, or a combination of length and certain characters. If you give a few examples I can give it a shot.

Comment: I believe the string will be splittable by the `(` character. The string will have many words, and will sometimes have words in parenthesis. I will give a few examples in the original question.

Comment: I thought something such as =Replace(MYFIELD.VALUE,"(","(" & vbCrLf) Would work in the Number>Format Expression, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Things are never as simple as you'd hope! Have a look at the above expanded answer, which works with your data.

Comment: Looks good. I'll accept it as the answer because I could apply it to my situation, but for future use and for the use of others, is there a way to apply the same logic to the Textbox `Properties > Number > Custom` formatting?

Comment: Thanks! You can only really apply the **Format** options to numeric and date/time data types, so it's not going to help in this case, unfortunately.

Comment: You can also use Environment.NewLine()

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue while doing my project. And I would like to share my steps for this. Create individual placehloders within the textbox by selecting the expression and format each as you desired. You can easily add extra line by just moving the another item(another placeholder) to next line(by pressing enter-on the keyboard)
Here I created individual placeholders inside the list, gave the names and format just as I want.
[image]