# SSRS - new line on report field

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

My query returns a field like "In my honest opinion \r\n you guys can help me!". When I display this field on my report, the lines don't "break" as expected... what should I do?

Comment: Does the field contain the actual string `\r\n`?

Comment: @DavidG yes it does... input is via textbox and the actual text is often much larger...

Comment: Why would you expect SSRS to convert them to newlines?

Comment: @DavidG a regular textbox does... and right-clicking the component gives you "TextBox Properties"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Textbox Formatting In SSRS 2008 - Break Line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141650/textbox-formatting-in-ssrs-2008-break-line)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Expression:

```
=Replace(Fields!YourField.Value, "\r\n", System.Environment.NewLine)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found and answer:
Right Click textbox -> Expression and then:
`=Fields!YourColumn.Value.ToString().Replace(",",vbCrLf)`