# TSQL to SSRS, how insert new line char but in SQL-SQL-SQL for SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I'm playing how I can insert some spec char in my stored procedure in SQL so my SSRS box will put them in new lines (* please don't confuse with any SSRS formatting/expression, `char(10)`, `vbcrlf` etc...). Additionally my input comes from xml like in snippet below, I tried all and nothing worked, I also tried to insert $ and later replace in SSRS box and this also strangely didn't work, is it possible to do ideally without going into SSRS formatting ?

Thanks all !

```
   ***    =Replace("$",vbcrlf)

; WITH cte AS (SELECT 'Line aaaaaa' Order_Desc  UNION  Select 'Line 22222' Proc_CODE  UNION SELECT  'Line 33333333' Proc_Code )
select
STUFF((SELECT
                ', ' + ord.Order_Desc   As [text()]   
                --',$' + ord.Order_Desc   As [text()] 
               FROM cte ord
               ORDER BY ord.Order_Desc
               FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,2,'') AS  Order_All
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696774/ssrs-new-line-on-report-field

Comment: marc hi, why you removed SSRS tug ? Just curious

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @LineBreak NVARCHAR(100)
SET @LineBreak = 'First line content.' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 'Second line 
content.'
PRINT  @LineBreak
```